# sparse matrix causes Segmentation fault exit code 139

Tags: scipy, segmentation-fault, sparse-matrix, gensim, exit-code

When working with a sparse matrix, it abruptly kills the kernel and exit code 139.
This happened when working with Gensim, which uses the sparse matrix format.

The failure happens when multiplying the matrix with another matrix, or even when using `matrix.sum()`.

the matrix was created using scipy:

```
matrix = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(num_terms, num_docs), dtype=dtype)
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the shape of the matrix (num_terms) didn't match the max(indices) which causes numpy to make erroneous assumptions about memory addresses.

This can easily be avoided if after creating the matrix we call:

```
matrix.check_format()
```

which makes some sanity checks on the matrix.
if using gensim, just use a high num_features. It doesn't have to be your actual number of features, as long as it's not lower than the actual number.

edit for more details:

with gensim you might be working on document similarity using:

```
sim_method = gensim.similarities.SparseMatrixSimilarity(documents, num_features=max_index)
```

if "documents" contain a higher id than max_index, it will cause a bug.

gensim simply wraps the scipy sparse matrix object. to call the check_format on it use:

```
sim_method.index.check_format()
```

Though a more likely bug can occur when you're trying to use this similarity method on another corpus of documents to get their similarity scores.

```
sim_method[query_documents]
```

again if query_documents contain an id higher than the max_index given at the time of the creation of the sim method - it will cause the bug.

Here gensim hides the scipy matrix completely so you can't call check_format directly, you'll just have to check your own input and make sure there's no bug there.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9965

Comment: The relevance to gensim would be clearer if you mentioned or showed which gensim code you were using. (Which class/method can you supply a `num_features` to that avoids the problem? And, does that really avoid any issues even if the matrix would fail a `check_format()` test?)

Comment: True, I added detail to make the gensim issue clearer